# excel macro to format data

Tags: string, excel, formatting

I have the data format like below,

```
Date         User            Time         Status     Domain
2011Apr18   ID:user1)   10:26:55.078>   loggedinto  A
2011Apr18   ID:user1)   14:09:31.010>   loggedout   A
2011Apr18   ID:user1)   14:10:37.473>   loggedinto  A
2011Apr18   ID:user1)   15:59:55.899>   loggedinto  A
2011Apr18   ID:user1)   16:22:05.335>   loggedout   A
2011Apr18   ID:user2)   16:59:00.769>   loggedinto  A
2011Apr18   ID:user2)   17:14:52.169>   loggedout   A
2011Apr19   ID:user1)   10:05:44.102>   loggedinto  A
2011Apr19   ID:user3)   11:54:27.713>   loggedinto  C
```

I need to have the above data in following format using excel macro..here again based on domain,country needs to be mapped like(A->India,B->China)...Pls help across

```
Date            user      Logged into      Logged out    Domain   Country
2011Apr18   ID:user1)   15:59:55.899>   16:22:05.335>        A    India
2011Apr18   ID:user1)   16:22:05.335>   17:14:52.169>        A    India
2011Apr18   ID:user2)   16:59:00.769>   10:05:44.102>        A    India
2011Apr18   ID:user2)   17:14:52.169>   15:59:55.899>        A    India
2011Apr19   ID:user1)   10:05:44.102>   17:14:52.169>        B    China
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll have to use VBA, especially to handle cases where a user logs in twice on the same domain without logging out, e.g. lines 3 and 4 of your example. What would you like the result to be in such cases?

Comment: @corbett:then let the logout time field be empty for those records.but i need that format by anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote here a little script for you. Start ReFormat() to create the new table. It reads the current data in the active sheet and puts it into an array. Then I create the new table in the same sheet starting at G1.

Please give me a feedback it was a bit of work. (if it is working for you accepting the answer is just fine).

```
Option Explicit

Dim DataArray() As String
Dim lngRow As Long, lngLastRow As Long
Dim intColumn As Integer

Sub ReFormat()

    Dim ResultTable As Range
    Dim CurrentResultRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    FillSourceArray

    Set ResultTable = ActiveSheet.Range("G1")
    CurrentResultRow = 0

    ResultTable.Offset(CurrentResultRow, 0).Value = "Date"
    ResultTable.Offset(CurrentResultRow, 1).Value = "user"
    ResultTable.Offset(CurrentResultRow, 2).Value = "Logged into"
    ResultTable.Offset(CurrentResultRow, 3).Value = "Logged out"
    ResultTable.Offset(CurrentResultRow, 4).Value = "Domain"
    ResultTable.Offset(CurrentResultRow, 5).Value = "Country"

    CurrentResultRow = CurrentResultRow + 1

    For i = 1 To lngLastRow - 1
        If (DataArray(i, 3) = "loggedinto") Then
            ResultTable.Offset(CurrentResultRow, 0).Value = DataArray(i, 0)
            ResultTable.Offset(CurrentResultRow, 1).Value = DataArray(i, 1)
            ResultTable.Offset(CurrentResultRow, 2).Value = DataArray(i, 2)
            ResultTable.Offset(CurrentResultRow, 3).Value = SearchLogOut(DataArray(i, 1), i + 1)
            ResultTable.Offset(CurrentResultRow, 4).Value = DataArray(i, 4)
            ResultTable.Offset(CurrentResultRow, 5).Value = SearchCountry(DataArray(i, 4))
            CurrentResultRow = CurrentResultRow + 1
        End If

    Next i

End Sub

Function SearchLogOut(user As String, Start As Integer) As String
    Dim i As Long

    For i = Start To lngLastRow - 1
        If ((DataArray(i, 1) = user) And (DataArray(i, 3) = "loggedout")) Then
            SearchLogOut = DataArray(i, 2)
            Exit For
        ElseIf ((DataArray(i, 1) = user) And (DataArray(i, 3) = "loggedinto")) Then
            SearchLogOut = ""
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Function

Function SearchCountry(Country As String) As String
    Select Case Country
        Case "A"
            SearchCountry = "India"
        Case "B"
            SearchCountry = "China"
    End Select

End Function

Sub FillSourceArray()

    'Read the Source Data
    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim DataArray(lngLastRow - 1, 4)

    For lngRow = 1 To lngLastRow
      For intColumn = 1 To 5
        DataArray(lngRow - 1, intColumn - 1) = Cells(lngRow, intColumn)
      Next intColumn
    Next lngRow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple mapping from A -> India and B -> China, please look at the VLOOKUP function. Here's a simple example: a8 to b11 are

```
a China
b India
c Russia
d Brazil
```

and if you have an "a" in a2 then this vlookup function will do what you desire:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$A$8:$B$11,2)
```

where a2 is the lookup value, $a$8:$b$11 is the table, and 2 means you want to return column b (the second column).